# is it compulsory to use .\SQLEXPRESS as value for data source in case of AttachDBfilename keyword?

Tags: .net, sql-server, ado.net, connection-string, sql-server-express

```
data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial File Name=|DataDirectory|ASPNET.mdf;Integrated Security=SSPI;User Instance=true
```

i am using above connection string. It is working fine. But when change data source ".\SQLEXPRESS" to "localhos" it raise error "Invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename'".
And my second question, what is the use of keyword "User Instace".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `server` instead of `data source` to get connected locally:

```
Server=(local);Initial File Name=|DataDirectory|ASPNET.mdf;Integrated Security=SSPI;User Instance=true
```

The use of user instance is to make fully previlaged SQL Server instance to a user with limited administrative previlaged on the computer.

Answer (score 1):

Only SQL Server Express Edition supports `attachdbfilename` option. So it follows that your data source **must** be an Express instance. It can be named *anything* and it can be the default instance, but it must be an Express edition. It looks like in your case you have two instances, one named `SQLEXPRESS` and a default one, and the one named `SQLEXPRESS` is an Express edition, while the default one is not. Again, is not the name of the instance that matters, is the engine edition you're connecting to.

You don't need to know anything about User Instance. Forget them.